# Primefaces barChart not displaying when empty data from database

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

i'm working on primefaces barChart that consumes data from database, everything works fine except when there's not data coming from the database, it causes a blank and blocked page and when i opened chrome console the javascript error say  "Uncaught Error: No data specified", so how can i deal with this case to display correctly the barChart when no data specified

Comment: I think I had the same problem - I made an outputText ("No data found" or something) that would be rendered instead in that case

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar how can I get to know if the chart is empty?

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but if you don't add the series to the barchart at all if there are no data I guess you can do like <h:outputText value="..." rendered="#{empty bean.barChart.series}". If that for some reason don't work you can just have a boolean on the bean (private Boolean noData) and set to true if there is no data, and check for that in the rendered attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render the chart you can fill it with "empty" data:

```
horizontalBarModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel();
 ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries();
    series.setLabel("seriesLabel");
    series.set("1", 0);
horizontalBarModel.addSeries(series);
```

If you just don't want to render the chart when there's no data, adding a boolean to your model and setting it to true/false when the data is filled can be a good option:

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{horizontalBarModel}" rendered="#{!emptyChart}"/>
```